# what is the c# equivalent of Iterator in Java

Tags: c#, java, iterator

I am manually converting Java to C# and have the following code:

```
for (Iterator<SGroup> theSGroupIterator = SGroup.getSGroupIterator();
     theSGroupIterator.hasNext();)
{
    SGroup nextSGroup = theSGroupIterator.next();
}
```

Is there an equivalent of `Iterator<T>` in C# or is there a better C# idiom?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The direct equivalent in C# would be [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the code would look something like this:

```
SGroup nextSGroup;
using(IEnumerator<SGroup> enumerator = SGroup.GetSGroupEnumerator())
{
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        nextSGroup = enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

However the idiomatic way would be:

```
foreach(SGroup group in SGroup.GetSGroupIterator())
{
    ...
}
```

and have `GetSGroupIterator` return an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and probably rename it to `GetSGroups()` or similar).

Answer (score 3):

In .NET in general, you are going to use the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.  This will return an `IEnumerator<T>` which you can call the MoveNext method and Current property on to iterate through the sequence.

In C#, the foreach keyword does all of this for you.  Examples of how to use foreach can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in C#, its called an [Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is supported by C# via IEnumerator/IEnumerable, there is a better idiom: foreach

```
foreach (SGroup nextSGroup in items)
{
    //...
}
```

for details, see MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(VS.71).aspx